# compute the integral $\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{\mid x-x_0\mid} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Does someone know an easy way to compute the integral
$\frac{1}{R^24\pi}\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{\mid x-x_0\mid} dx=\frac{1}{d}$, where $\Omega$ is the surface of a sphere of radius $R$, $x_0$ is a point on the surface or outside the sphere and $d$ is the distance between $x_0$ and the center of the sphere?
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I suspect that the correct result is $$ \frac{1}{4\pi R^2} \int_{\partial B(a, R)} \frac{1}{|x_0 - x|} \, d\sigma_x = \frac{1}{|x_0 - a|}, $$ where $B(a, R) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is the open ball of radius $R$ centered at $a$ and $x_0 \notin B(a, R)$. This is a direct consequence of the [*mean value property*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) applied to the function $$u(x) = \frac{1}{|x_0 - x|}$$ which is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{x_0\}$.

Comment: Dear  Sangchul Lee, thank you for your answer. Don't we need the function to be harmonic inside the ball in order to apply the mean value property?

Comment: Yes. That is why we require $x_0 \notin B(a, R)$, since we need $B(a, R) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{x_0\}$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much!

Comment: I edited the question as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume that ${\bf x_0}=(0,0,d)$ with $d\geq R>0$, and the center of the sphere is ${\bf a}=(0,0,0)$.  Then by using spherical coordinates
$$(R\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),R\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),R\cos(\phi))$$ with $(\theta,\phi)\in [0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]$, we obtain
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{4\pi R^2} \int_{\partial B({\bf a}, R)} \frac{1}{|{\bf x_0 - x}|} \, d\sigma_{\bf x}
&=\frac{1}{4\pi R^2} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\frac{R^2\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{R^2\sin(\phi)^2+(R\cos(\phi)-d)^2}}\,d\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(\phi)}{
\sqrt{R^2+d^2-2Rd\cos(\phi)}}\,d\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{2Rd}\left[
\sqrt{d^2+R^2-2Rd\cos(\phi)}
\right]_0^{\pi}
=\frac{|d-R|-|d+R|}{2Rd}=\frac{1}{d}.
\end{align*}

P.S. By the way if $0\leq d< R$, then following the same procedure we find that the integral is $1/R$ (it is constant).

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I have tried, but unfortunately I couldn't simplify the integral further. May I ask you for a further hint?

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clear!

Comment: @tigro You are welcome. By the way if $0\leq d< R$, then following the same procedure we find that the integral is $1/R$ (it is constant).